# Can you build a hyper::Request from a String?

Tags: rust, hyper

I'm trying to write an intercepting proxy. I originally used hyper as a server, as that was relatively straightforward, but if a request was malformed, hyper returned a response before I could pass the request on to the upstream server. I'd like to avoid that so I'm looking to use `tokio::net::TcpListener` to receive requests from the browser, and then use hyper as a client to forward the request to the remote server.

As I'm using the `TcpListener` and subsequesnt `TcpStream` the request comes through as `u8` which I'm then converting to a `String`. Is there a way to easily convert this to a `hyper::Request` or would I need to write the code to convert this myself?

If the latter, does anyone have any suggestions for an alternative library that would allow me to create an HTTP request from a string?

Comment: I'm not sure any HTTP client library is going to provide for making malformed requests.

Comment: So it's not necessarily a requirement that a malformed request is accepted, just that I am able to present it to the user of the proxy without it automatically returning a 400.

Comment: It looks like you will have to parse the incoming bytes into a `Request` instance and use a Hyper client to perform such request as there's no `From<Vec<u8>>` or `From<&[u8]>` implementation for `hyper::Request`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

I found out you could have HTTP request being parsed from bytes using this crate from *seanmonstar* (the same author from Hyper):

https://github.com/seanmonstar/httparse

Perhaps using your TCP Stream and consuming the incoming bytes using this **httparse** crate would be enough.

### Original Answer

If I'm not mistaken you are trying to create an instance of `hyper::Request` from a byte stream or a byte array (`&[u8]`) that you are getting from the `TcpListener`.

To have a Hyper server handle requests properly and also use your already existent TCP Listener you could make use of: https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.11/hyper/server/struct.Server.html#method.from_tcp

And then you could use this other crate to have that request streamed to the proxied server:
https://github.com/tafia/hyper-proxy

Comment: Thanks Esteban, the httparse crate is exactly what I'm after.

Comment: Awesome! Im glad to help you, keep it up :)